# how can i further understand the compilation process used by gcc?

Tags: gcc, compilation

I was trying to reverse engineer some psp programs developed using the free
pspsdk

https://sourceforge.net/projects/minpspw/

I noticed that i created a function to see how MIPS handles more than 4 arguments (a0-a4).
Everyone i know has told me that they get passed onto the stack.
To my surprise, that 5th argument was actually passed to register t0 and to compiler didn't even use the stack!

it also inlined a function without even having used a jal or jump to it. (obvious optimization).
Altough there was indeed a space a memory and you could double check by using print with function pointer argument. That actual code that was executed was automatically inlined without the need of a function call instruction.

^^ but that doesn't really benefit me for a reverse engineer attempt...

there is a man page for this version of gcc. and it takes seconds to install if anyone is able to provide it's man for compilation if there is one. 
It's so long i don't even know how to reference information reliably

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How arguments are passed is specified by the ABI (application binary interface).  So you have to find respective documents.

Moreover, there is more than one such ABI, namely `n32` and `n64`.  In the case of `mips-gcc`, some of the decisions are commented in the GCC sources like in [./gcc/config/mips/mips.h](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/config/mips/mips.h;h=3ce0c19a29a0139f7e491cafd2976a2a42e33a83;hb=ad8e2415d6e2dc7c6f1206e78d48f999ff6b0bc4#l2445)

```
/* This structure has to cope with two different argument allocation
   schemes.  Most MIPS ABIs view the arguments as a structure, of which
   the first N words go in registers and the rest go on the stack.  If I
   < N, the Ith word might go in Ith integer argument register or in a
   floating-point register.  For these ABIs, we only need to remember
   the offset of the current argument into the structure.

   The EABI instead allocates the integer and floating-point arguments
   separately.  The first N words of FP arguments go in FP registers,
   the rest go on the stack.  Likewise, the first N words of the other
   arguments go in integer registers, and the rest go on the stack.  We
   need to maintain three counts: the number of integer registers used,
   the number of floating-point registers used, and the number of words
   passed on the stack.

   We could keep separate information for the two ABIs (a word count for
   the standard ABIs, and three separate counts for the EABI).  But it
   seems simpler to view the standard ABIs as forms of EABI that do not
   allocate floating-point registers.

   So for the standard ABIs, the first N words are allocated to integer
   registers, and mips_function_arg decides on an argument-by-argument
   basis whether that argument should really go in an integer register,
   or in a floating-point one.  */
```

There are more such comments in the [mips backend](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=gcc.git;a=tree;f=gcc/config/mips;).  Search for "cumulative" or "CUMULATIVE" in `mips.c` and `mips.h`.